# How to switch datasource before running jasper report by rest-client?

Tags: jasper-reports, repository, datasource, rest-client

I have more datasources configured in Jasperserver repository. I can get the report, assing parameters, run it from my application and pass the result PDF stream to the client.
I expect I would be able to simply switch the source database. There are predefined parameters "REPORT_DATA_SOURCE" or "REPORT_CONNECTION". The rest-client interface allows to pass only string values to them. I expected this will work:

```
runReportAdapter.parameter("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE","/datasources/my_alternative_datasource");
runReportAdapter.run();
```

but it doesn't work. No error is reported but the data are retrieved from original datasource.